# Got `internal error in __sub: no metatable` error in Lua and Torch

Tags: lua, torch

I tried to create a image-to-image model by `pix2pix` (https://github.com/phillipi/pix2pix) and followed Getting Started instruction.
Then, downloaded facades dataset by bash `./datasets/download_dataset.sh facades`
and run `DATA_ROOT=./datasets/facades name=facades_generation which_direction=BtoA th train.lua`

but I got the following error.

> ~/torch-cl/install/bin/luajit: ./models.lua:69: internal error in
>   __sub: no metatable stack traceback:  [C]: in function '__sub'    ./models.lua:69: in function 'defineG_unet'     train.lua:110: in
>   function 'defineG'    train.lua:146: in main chunk    [C]: in function
>   'dofile'
>     ...i/torch-cl/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:145: in
>   main chunk    [C]: at 0x010ec81ce0

Does anyone know how I can fix this?
I'm new to Lua and Torch, so have no idea how to fix this.

Thank you

this is run on Mac OSX
python2.7

Comment: What has this got to do with TensorFlow?

Comment: Have you tried the torch [60-minute blitz](https://github.com/soumith/cvpr2015/blob/master/Deep%20Learning%20with%20Torch.ipynb)? This would help debug any installation problems.